# How to fix 'AttributeError: type object 'pyfmi.fmi.ModelBase' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__''

Tags: cython, fmi

I am importing pyfmi and get this error message. I am using Spyder (Python 3.6) on windows.

I also downloaded the latest version of Cython 0.29.13

```
import pyfmi
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-df481fa81f2d>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyfmi

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyfmi\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .fmi import FMUModel, load_fmu, FMUModelME1, FMUModelME2

  File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 165, in init pyfmi.fmi

AttributeError: type object 'pyfmi.fmi.ModelBase' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Comment: How did you install `pyfmi`? I think that what version of Cython you have installed is irrelevant - it's what version that `pyfmi` was built with.

Comment: Hi David, I install it under the Anaconda cmd prompt. I use the command: conda install pyfmi-2.5.3-py36hc8d92b1_0.tar.bz2

Comment: If I search for that filename it does at least look like it was built with an up-to-date version of Cython. You might have more luck reporting this as a bug to either conda or the pyfmi maintainers, if they're distributing a package that can't be used.